# Check if sub document is found in $project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find all the trips provided by a company, grouped by the driver of the bus, and check if a given passenger was part of the trip.

Content is an array that can have reference to multiple models: User, Cargo, etc.

I can somewhat achieve my desired result using:

```
    traveled: { $in: [ passengerId, "$content.item" ] },
```

But i want to confirm that the matched id is indeed a 'User'(passenger). I have tried:

```
    traveled: { $and: [
        { $in: [ passengerId, "$content.item" ] },
        { $in: [ `Passenger`, "$content.kind" ] },
   ]},
```

But it also matches if the passed id has a kind of 'Cargo' when there is another content with a kind of 'User' is inside the array.

```
    // Trip
    const schema = Schema({
        company: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company', required: false },
        driver: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        ....
        content: [{
            kind: { type: String, required: true },
            item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, refPath: 'content.kind', required: true }
        }]
    });

    const Trip = mongoose.model('Trip', schema, 'trips');

    Trip.aggregate([
        { $match: { company: companyId } },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                driver: 1,
                description: 1,
                traveled: { $in: [ passengerId, "$content.item" ] },
                // traveled: { $and: [
                //     { $in: [ passengerId, "$content.item" ] },
                //     { $in: [ `Passenger`, "$content.kind" ] },
                // ]},
            }
        },
        {
            $group : {
                _id: "$driver",
                content: {
                    $push: {
                        _id: "$_id",
                        description: "$description",
                        traveled: "$traveled",
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    ]).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: are you looking to see if all the item kinds is Passenger in content array ?

Comment: At the moment I am just trying to match a single Passenger. I just want to confirm that the object that matches the content.item == passengerId also matched content.kind == 'User'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`no $elemMatch operator`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14876) in `$project` stage. So to use mimic similar functionality you can create `$filter` with `$size` being `$gt` > 0.

Something like

```
"traveled":{
  "$gt":[
    {"$size":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$content",
        "as":"c",
        "cond":{
          "$and":[
            {"$eq":["$$c.item",passengerId]},
            {"$eq":["$$c.kind","User"]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }},
    0
  ]
}
```